# Move drawing on window with Win32

Tags: winapi

I've drawn a lot of scattered pixels on a screen. I want to move them all a few pixels to the left. Doesn't matter what's left on the last columns of pixels – I can deal with them after the fact.

I tried using `SetPixel` to redraw the translated image, and though it worked, it wasn't as fast as I would have wanted. So I started searching the web for a specific function for my purpose. I came across `SetWorldTransform`, but from what I can gather, this serves only to translate coordinates, not full regions. I also found `OffsetRgn`, but again, this seems to have another purpose. I haven't found anything else that seems promising.

Is there anything I can do that's faster than the naive `SetPixel`?

Comment: Assuming the pixels are the *only* thing drawn, lookup [`ScrollWindowEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-scrollwindowex). Otherwise, maybe [Move a bitmap around a window quickly in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622117/move-a-bitmap-around-a-window-quickly-in-c).

Comment: @dxiv That was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!